# Uneven tree of processes using fork()

Tags: c, fork

I have to construct a tree of processes using `fork()` in C. I get a sequence of numbers from standard input (for example: 1 5 0 3) and those numbers tell me how many children each node has. If we take the example then the root process creates 1 child, then this one child creates 5 children of its own, then from those 5 children the first one doesn't create any children, the second one creates 3 of them and then we're done. After this is complete the root process calls `pstree` that draws out the tree.

Here is a picture of the example:

[image]

My question is how can I make new children from a specific node? One needs to create 0 new processes and the next one needs to create 3 of them. I don't know how to distinguish so that only that specific child makes new children and not all of them. Also I'm not sure how to use `pstree`, because the tree is normally already gone when `pstree` gets called. I know I can `wait()` for children to execute first but last ones do not have any children to wait for so they end too fast.

I've written code that creates the example. Need ideas how to generalize this for different inputs. Also can someone show me how to call pstree from this code because I can't seem to get it working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main() {

pid_t pid;
pid_t temppid;
pid_t temppid2;
int  root_pid;
int status;

root_pid = getpid();

pid = fork(); // creates a child from root
if (pid == 0) { // if child
    pid = fork(); // fork again (child#1)
    if (pid != 0) { // if not child of child#1
        temppid = getpid(); // get pid
        if (getpid() == temppid) { // create child#2
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0) {
                temppid2 = getpid();
                if (getpid() == temppid2) { // create child#1
                    fork();
                }
                if (getpid() == temppid2) { // create child#2
                    fork();
                }
                if (getpid() == temppid2) { // create child#3
                    fork();
                }
            }
        }
        if (getpid() == temppid) { // create child#3
            fork();
        }
        if (getpid() == temppid) { // create child#4
            fork();
        }
        if (getpid() == temppid) { // create child#5
            fork();
        }
    }
}
else {
    // create another child from root
    pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            // run pstree in this child with pid from root
        }
}

while (1) {
    sleep(1);
}
}
```

Comment: `pstree` isn't a general purpose tree-printing utility, you can't use it for that. For the other part of your question: where is your code? No-one can help you without seeing how you've coded your tree structure.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Is this a homework question?

Comment: Are the numbers you get in depth-first order or breadth-first order (or something else)? The example doesn't make that clear. For example if the first number in the example would be 2 and the second number would 1, would the third number describe the number of children of the first child process of the first child process of the root or the number of children of the second child process of the root?

Comment: @Mat He doesn't have a tree structure. He wants to create a hierarchy of child processes and print that using pstree.

Comment: It is a homework question and I can't solve it. In my mind fork() clones the process so every process is the same. I know I can check if new process is a child or parent but this still isn't giving me an option to create a different number of children for each created child.

There is no code yet other than reading numbers and for loop that calls fork if process is a child. Obviously that doen't work and I'm here for some clarification of how fork works or some hints or something.

Comment: @sepp2k The numbers are in breadth first order. First one is root, second one is child at far left, third one is to the right of the previous node and so on.

Comment: @ragezor Do you know how you would do it for a specific example? For example do you know how you would write a function that takes no input and creates the pattern for 1 5 0 3?

Comment: "*...so they end too fast.*" what makes the children end?

Comment: I guess for a specific problem I would nest if statements.

They end because the program is over I think. I'm not sure. One part of the problem is that I can't see what my code does. If I could see the tree structure that gets created I would have easier time.

So first I need to get pstree working.

This is my sample code which in my understanding would fork like this: root -> child1 -> child2

Comment: this is the code:
`
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 pid_t pid, root_pid;
 
 root_pid = getpid();
 
 pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0) {
  fork();
 }
 
 execlp("pstree", "pstree", "-c", root_pid, NULL);
 
 return 0;
}
`

Comment: I also don't know how to format code on this site..

Comment: @ragezor : Edit your question and add the code there. You will be able to format it there. It's a very good question that has been given for homework. So I'd suggest you try your best and spend time and think over it. Once you get the idea how to do it, you will be able to easily do it.

Comment: The code you posted will work only for the example you have shown and not for any input read from stdin. To help you,I can suggest one thing. Try to write the program based on input like :- 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1 6 3 7 3 8 3 9 ( which means the same example you took.

Comment: @ragezor To make the formatting appear as wanted do **not** paste in `TAB`s, but use an appropriate number of `BLANK`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

For `pstree`, the solution is simple - every process, after doing what it should, would go to sleep (for, say, a minute).
Then you can use `pstree` to see what's going on.

For forking the right number of times, it seems that the problem is with parsing the input, not with forking.
I'd start with writing code that reads the input and, instead of forking, just prints the tree of processes you want to create. Once you have this clear, it shouldn't be able to do the forks right.

Comment: I still get no output from pstree. I thought this is because they end too fast but maybe I'm doing something else wrong.
This is how I call it:
execlp("pstree", "pstree", "-n", root_pid, NULL);
sleep(5);
return 0;

Comment: Why run `pstree` as part of your application? Just open another terminal and run `pstree` there. Anyway, the bug may be that `root_pid` is an integer, and should be a string.

Comment: any instructions after the execlp succeeds will not matter because the process is replaced with the new code. In your case, sleep and return will never be executed. If execlp fails, then sleep and return will be executed. So 1) put printfs around the sleep 5. 2) check the exec return value for success.

Comment: I think it's best not to use `execlp`. If you want `pstree` in order to see that your code works, run it from outside your code. This way it won't break it.

Comment: I have to use it because its an automated grading script which depends on pstree output. I'm running it from another terminal for now.

Answer (score 1):

For just testing the hierachy your app created:

Instead of placing a

```
return 0;
```

as last statement put a

```
while (1)
  sleep(1);
```

This make the process run for ever until you press `Ctrl-C`.

After you started the app use another terminal and issue a `pstree` to inspect the process hierachy the app created.

To clean up (and if on linux) issue a `killall <app name>`.

Comment: `while (1) pause();` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

My one suggestion is that you use the return value of `fork` to tell if your code is running in the child process or parent process.